# Как увеличить кол-во подключений websocket ratchet?

Tags: php, windows, websocket, ratchet

Я настроил `websocket` `ratchet` по инструкции:
http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world

В `vps` `windows server 2016` + `xampp`.

Все прекрасно работает, только вот кол-во подключений зависает на 255:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нашел вот эту ссылку:
https://rtcamp.com/tutorials/linux/increase-open-files-limit/
Но там настройки для `linux`.

Подскажите пжл, как правильно увеличить кол-во подключений (например до 50k).

Comment: Случайно не это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003756/is-there-a-limit-practical-or-otherwise-to-the-number-of-web-sockets-a-page-op ?

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev, к сожалению нет

Comment: @Амирхон 255 - макс. число соединений на 1 клиент (браузер). Об этом на гите написано в решениях. Ссылочка выше - решение ваших бед по идее. На всякий случай почитайте, может что-то найдете - https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/issues/376